# Back Button Displays Incorrect Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I'm encountering some strange behavior with regards to the back button and `Fragments`. Here is my situation, I have 3 `Fragments`, `f1`, `f2`, and f3`.` There is a `Button` within `f1` which brings up `f2`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .addToBackStack("f1")
    .replace(R.id.fragHook, f2,
     TAG).commit();
```

This transaction works perfectly. I can hit the go back and forth between the 2 fragments just find. Within f2, I have a `RecyclerView` which the user can select a cell. When the user selects a cell, I bring up `f3` but I don't add `f2` to the backstack:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragHook, f3)
    .commit();
```

The `Fragment` `f3` is displayed properly. And on  the first time with this process, I click the back button and `f1` is displayed properly again. The problem now comes if I repeat those same steps. The `Button` within `f1` is clicked, which brings up `f2` with the `RecyclerView`. A cell is then selected bringing up `f3` for a second time. Now when I click the back button, the fragment `f2` appears.

I checked and the `onCreateView` is called for both `f1` and `f2`. What could be causing the `f2` `Fragment` to appear?

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the back button and check for fragments focus and do the right flow manually

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it could be doing by adding all the fragment to backstack .**

When BackButton press and CurrentFragment is f3 then write

super.onbackPressed() two times else one time.